# Finding similar patterns in numbers using mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql. Still learning things about it.

I have a table that has a column called UPC that is char(13)

I am finding that there are records where there are patterns like:

```
4009426030
04009426030
```

Having UPCs like those above means I have two records for the same item. I need to find all the records that are the same so I can merge them. So I tried

```
SELECT * 
  FROM products p1 
 WHERE prod_id in (
     SELECT prod_id
       FROM products p2 
      WHERE lpad(p2.upc, 13, '0') = lpad(p1.upc, 13, '0') 
        AND p2.upc != p1.upc 
)
```

My idea was that I would find the records where `'4009426030' != '04009426030'` but `'0004009426030' == '0004009426030'` so I don't match on the same records, only different ones.

But I get no results! Can someone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd07a/7)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE products
    (`prod_id` int,`upc` varchar(25))
;

INSERT INTO products
    (`prod_id`, `upc`)
VALUES
    (1, '4009426030'),
    (2, '04009426030')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products p1 
inner join products p2 on lpad(p2.upc, 13, '0') = lpad(p1.upc, 13, '0') 
        AND p2.upc > p1.upc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd07a/7/0)**:

```
| prod_id |         upc | prod_id |        upc |
|---------|-------------|---------|------------|
|       2 | 04009426030 |       1 | 4009426030 |
```